# Soundcloud API / Downloading sets (playlists)

Tags: soundcloud

I'm developing a custom player widget with the SoundCloud API. I want to allow downloading a complete CD/EP that is represented by a set/playlist as a zip package or something alike. The *playlist* REST request gives a JSON result with a field 'downloadable', but not the field 'download_url' as is the case with a *track* REST request.

Is it possible to let the widget user download a complete set at once, maybe for premium memberships only? If not, will this become possible in the future for any of the premium accounts?

I think it is very useful for allot of users that want to offer a new released album as a downloadable gift for promotion. Currently a user has to click on the download button for each track seperately.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start with a sidenote: we are not SoundCloud support so telling us you would really *really* like a feature is not really *really* going to accomplish much.

Now to your question: I'm sure it is possible with some serverside work. You could download the tracks on the serverside and pack it for the user and make it available to them.

Comment: Soundcloud API support makes use of stackoverflow according to their website to answer questions: http://developers.soundcloud.com/support. I Was hoping to reach someone from the soundcloud team. Your idea of handeling and packaging the files server-side is my last resort. It would require much bandwidth from my hosting account. I'd rather pay that additional cost to soundcloud and have a more convenient solution.